# Why are some setxkbmap options ignored?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, nixos

in share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev/lst, I find this set of options for ctrl

```
  ctrl                 Ctrl key position
  ctrl:nocaps          Caps Lock as Ctrl
  ctrl:lctrl_meta      Left Ctrl as Meta
  ctrl:swapcaps        Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock
  ctrl:ac_ctrl         At left of 'A'
  ctrl:aa_ctrl         At bottom left
  ctrl:rctrl_ralt      Right Ctrl as Right Alt
  ctrl:menu_rctrl      Menu as Right Ctrl
  ctrl:ctrl_ralt       Right Alt as Right Ctrl
  ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl  Swap Left Alt key with Left Ctrl key
  ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl  Swap Left Win key with Left Ctrl key
  ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl_lwin Left Alt as Ctrl, Left Ctrl as Win, Left Win as Alt
```

Some of them work - if I run `setxkbmap -option -option 'ctrl:nocaps'`, I get the correct behavior. However, some of the others are ignored, for example `setxkbmap -option -option 'ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl_lwin'`.

One observation I've made is that the ignored options are displayed by `setxkbmap -query`, but not by `setxkbmap -print`. Here's a demonstration of this behavior.

```
$ setxkbmap -option -option ctrl:nocaps
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     us
variant:    colemak
options:    ctrl:nocaps
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(colemak)+inet(evdev)+ctrl(nocaps)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
$ setxkbmap -option -option ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl_lwin
$ setxkbmap -query                                  
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     us
variant:    colemak
options:    ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl_lwin
$ setxkbmap -print                                  
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(colemak)+inet(evdev)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

I don't know how to dig into this any deeper. Some further environment information is

- linux distribution is NixOs
- window manager is XMonad, display manager is SLiM, no desktop manager
- keyboard layout is colemak (problem persists if I switch to qwerty)
- setxkbmap version is 1.3.0 according to the man page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this appears to be because not all of the options listed in the file evdev.lst are also in the neighboring file evdev. I've asked a follow question as to why this is the case at [why does the file evdev in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules not match with evdev.lst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662464/why-does-the-file-evdev-in-usr-share-x11-xkb-rules-not-match-with-evdev-lst)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it happens because some options seem to not be compatible with others.

For example, if I set up shift key to unlock the caps lock (-option shift:breaks_caps), and at the same time set up alt-shift to switch between keyboard layouts, then shift no longer unlocks the caps lock. As soon as I change the layout switching combination from alt-shift to say, alt-ctrl, the option shift:breaks_caps reactivates.

Looks like a bug to me.